# ' For i in filenames ' creates an TypeError

Tags: python

I'm not sure what's wrong in this code :

```
import os
import re
regex = re.compile(r'\d+')

for f in os.listdir("F:/temptest2/"):
    fname = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    fext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if fext == ".DNG":
        fdngnum = regex.findall(fname)
        matchcount = 0
        for i in os.listdir("F:/temptest2/"):
            f2name = os.path.splitext(i)[0]
            if fdngnum in f2name:
                matchcount = matchcount + 1
        if matchcount < 2:
            print(f)
```

I get the following error on the line `if fdngnum in f2name:`

*`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`*

where it says f2name should be a string and not a list. But insn't it a string ? (I thought it acted as as a single string, for each passing through the for loop)

Thanks !

Comment: " it says f2name should be a string and not a list.". No, it says fdngnum should be a string. Left is the other side.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `findall` function returns a list:

**re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)**

`Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.`

Check [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for other methods that might help you ;) (You can also iterate over that list).

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall()` returns a list. Perhaps you meant to iterate over it, or just use `search()`?